# Array of pointers, pointing to bitmaps in progmem

Tags: android, c++, arrays, pointers, bitmap

I am in the process of drawing bitmaps to an OLED screen. 
Each image is formatted like

`const static unsigned char waddle_dee_0[] PROGMEM ={*bits*};

Currently, I have been trying to add animation and clean up the code. To do this, I have created the class “Bitmap”.

This class will store things such as the size, width, and an array containing a pointer to each frame of the image, such as

```
const static unsigned char* const waddle_table[] PROGMEM = {
  waddle_dee_0,
  waddle_dee_1,
  waddle_dee_2,
  waddle_dee_3,
  waddle_dee_4,
  waddle_dee_5
};
```

In Bitmap.cpp, I have a constructor and a function

```
#include "bitmaps.h"

Bitmap::Bitmap(double w, double h, uint8_t f, size_t s, const unsigned char* const b){
    setWidth(w);
    setHeight(h);
    setFrames(f);
    setSize(s);
    setAllFrames(b);
}

void Bitmap::drawFrames(){

size_t currSize = this->getSize();
uint8_t numbOfFrames = this->getFrames();
double width = this->getWidth();
double height = this->getHeight();

Serial.println(currSize);
Serial.println(numbOfFrames);

    for (int i = 0; i < numbOfFrames; i++)
    {
      const unsigned char* frameAt = this->getSingleFrame(i);
      drawBitmap(0,0,width,height, frameAt, currSize);
      delay(100);
    }

}
```

And in the header file I have the definitions

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "Arduino.h"

// ensure this library description is only included once
#ifndef Bitmap_h
#define Bitmap_h

// library interface description
class Bitmap
{
  // user-accessible "public" interface
  public:
    Bitmap(double w, double h, uint8_t f, size_t s, const unsigned char* const b);
    double getWidth(){return width;}
    double getHeight(){return height;}
    uint8_t getFrames(){return frames;}
    size_t getSize(){return size;}

    double setWidth(double w){width = w;}
    double setHeight(double h){height = h;}
    uint8_t setFrames(uint8_t f){frames = f;}
    size_t setSize(size_t s){size = s;}

    //const unsigned char* const* getFrameArr(){return bitmap_frames;}
    void drawFrames();
    const unsigned char* const* getAllFrames(){return bitmap_frames;}
    void setAllFrames(const unsigned char* const b){*bitmap_frames = b;}
    const unsigned char* getSingleFrame(uint8_t f){return bitmap_frames[f];}

private:
    double width;
    double height;
    uint8_t frames;
    size_t size;
    const unsigned char* const bitmap_frames[];
};
#endif
```

My issue comes from the array of pointers, and how to correctly copy those frames or correctly copy the pointers to a new array(bitmap_frames).
The goal is to have bitmap_frames be the same as the waddle_table array, so I can loop through the index to draw each bitmap one at a time in order. My code was working when I had a single hardcoded array, but after trying to generalize it i ran into a multitude of type errors and inconsistencies.

If anyone could lead me in the right direction, I seem to have gotten lost in the pointer system. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare `bitmap_frames` as const flexible array you can't copy to it and should initialize it in constructor:

```
Bitmap::Bitmap() : bitmap_frames {waddle_dee_0, waddle_dee_1, waddle_dee_2, waddle_dee_3, waddle_dee_4, waddle_dee_5} {}
```

Or you can declare `bitmap_frames` as static in class definition:

```
static const unsigned char *const bitmap_frames[];
```

And define it at source file:

```
const unsigned char *const Bitmap::bitmap_frames[] = {
  waddle_dee_0,
  waddle_dee_1,
  waddle_dee_2,
  waddle_dee_3,
  waddle_dee_4,
  waddle_dee_5};
```

Also you can just use `std::vector`:

```
const std::vector<const unsigned char*> bitmap_frames;
```

And in constructor:

```
Bitmap::Bitmap() : bitmap_frames(std::begin(waddle_table), std::end(waddle_table)) {}
```

Comment: How would i go about initializing it in the constructor, if the class gets passed a bitmap into it? As in, for bitmap_frames, it wont always be whats in waddle_table, it would be in whatever table i pass to it. The goal of the Bitmap class is to input a hardcoded table(in this case waddle_table), which is then stored in a variable in the class, bitmap_frames. If im not mistaken, your examples set the class variable bitmap_frames to the waddle_table by means of hard coding, not passing the waddle_table as a parameter. I believe i am misunderstanding the initialization list of the constructor.

Comment: So use the last example with vector, add parameter to constructor and pass it instead of `waddle_table`.